# sIFR problem in IE document.defaultView.getComputedStyle

Tags: internet-explorer, sifr

I have sIFR 3 r436 working perfectly in all browsers except IE.

IE throws 2 errors. The first is:
'document.defaultView.getComputedStyle' is null of not an object
This is on the sifr.js file

The second is:
'sIFR' is null or not an object
This one is happening I think due to the fact that the sifr.js script is failing in it's load.

Has anyone had anything like this before?

Thanks,
Jai

Comment: Could you provide some more info? Which version of IE? Any weirdness in its setup?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The CMS I use, Jojo, minifies every js and css file that it serves. When I finally worked out to test the file by bypassing this it worked straight away.